# MATLAB: Vectors, Sequential Elements and rand

Tags: matlab, vector, moving-average

This question is from [chegg.com](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-vector-n-elements-simple-moving-average-m-sequential-elements-vector-defined-write-s-q6177069).

Given a vector a of N elements a_{n},n =1,2,...,N, the simple moving average of m sequential elements of this vector is defined as

```
mu(j) = mu(j-1) + (a(m+j-1)-a(j-1))/m   for j = 2,3,...,(N-m+1)
```

where

```
mu(1) = sum(a(k))/m    for k = 1,2,...,m
```

Write a script that computes these moving averages when `a` is given by `a=5*(1+rand(N,1))`, where `rand` generates uniformly distributed random numbers. Assume that `N=100` and `m=6`. Plot the results using `plot(j,mu(j))` for `j=1,2,...,N-m+1`.

My current code is below, but I'm not sure where to go from here or if it's even right.

```
close all 
clear all
clc 
N = 100; 
m = 6; 
a = 5*(1+rand(N,1)); 
mu = zeros(N-m+1,1); 
mu(1) = sum(a(1:m)); 
for j=2 
    mu(j) = mu(j-1) + (a-a)/m 
end 
plot(1:N-m+1,mu)
```

Comment: What is the question? Please don't just paste a link as it may go stale and then nobody will be able to understand what this is about.

Comment: Given a vector a of N elements a_{n},n =1,2,...,N. The simple moving average of m sequential elements of this vector is defined as

\mu _{j} = \mu _{j-1} + \frac{a_{m+j-1}-a_{j-1}}{m}   j =2,3,...,(N-m+1)

where

\mu _{1} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k-1}^{m}a_{k}

Write a script that computes these moving averages when a is given by a=5*(1+rand(N,1)), where rand generates uniformly distributed random numbers. Assume that N=100 and m=6. Plot the results using plot(j,\mu _{j}) for j=1,2,...,N-m+1.

Comment: Hope you can follow that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll step you through the modifications.

Firstly, `mu(1)` was not fully defined. The equation given is slightly incorrect, but this is what it should be:

```
mu(1) = sum(a(1:m))/m;
```

then the `for` loop has to go from `j=2` to `j=N-m+1`

```
for j=2:N-m+1
```

and at each step, `mu(j)` is given by this formula, the same as given in the question

```
mu(j) = mu(j-1) + (a(m+j-1)-a(j-1))/m
```

And that's all you need to change!